# How can you check if a value entered is numeric?

Tags: c++, cin

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double money;
    cout << "Input the sum of money: ";
    cin >> money;
....
```

I have been trying to check if the value entered is a numeric value so that i can display an error message if another value (alphabetic letter) is entered and the code will loop back to ask for the input again (the money)

Comment: What's with the all caps title?

Comment: @Mysticial, What all caps title?

Comment: Why the title in caps?

Answer (score 2):

```
while ( ( cin >> money ) == false )
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the state of the stream after the input. For example

```
if ( !( std::cin >> money ) ) std::cout << "Oh, I made a mistake!\n";
```

And if you want to repeat the input you should call

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

Do not forget to include header `<limits>`